# Автозамена уведомлений

Tags: android

Ребята,у меня есть метод вывода уведомлений,который выводит уведомления пользователю.

Как мне сделать так,чтобы уведомления не автозаменялись?

Нужно чтобы они выводились отдельно: вылезло одно,человек не нажал,потом вылезло ОТДЕЛЬНО другое.

Код:

```
    public void pushText(String str1,String str2){
        //String url="http://"+str2;

        Context context = getApplicationContext();

        Intent intent=new Intent(context,WebActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(KEY_INTENT,str2);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getActivity(context,0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this);
// оставим только самое необходимое
        builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
                .setContentTitle("Hodite")
                .setContentText(str1); // Текст уведомления

        Notification notification = builder.build();
        notification.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND |
                Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
        // ставим флаг, чтобы уведомление пропало после нажатия
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        nm=(NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        nm.notify(NOTIFICATION_KEY,notification);
    }
```

Я думаю,что нужно менять NOTIFICATION_KEY,чтобы они не заменялись,а выводились отдельно друг от друга.

Так ли это?

Comment: Именно. Разные `NOTIFICATION_KEY` - отдельные уведомления. По мне, так попробовать было бы быстрее, чем задавать здесь вопрос.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот тут

```
nm.notify(NOTIFICATION_KEY,notification);
```

вам для каждого уведомления надо генерить уникальный NOTIFICATION_KEY. Т.е. если 
в трее висит уведомление с определенным ключем, то при создании второго уведомления с тем же ключем - первое будет заменено.

Например так

```
nm.notify((str1 + str2).hashCode(), notification);
```